# How to detach change detection from a single property instead of the whole component in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, performance, angular6, angular2-changedetection

I have a global `DataService` that is availbale in multiple components:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})

export class DataService {
  public data: JSON;

  constructor() {
    this.data = localStorage.getItem('data');
  }

  public getData(): JSON {
    return this.data;
  }
}
```

It's provided through `app.component.ts`:

```
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
  providers: [
    DataService
  ]
})

export class AppComponent {
  constructor() { }

}
```

… and used like this in components:

```
import { DataService } from './data.service';

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  public data: JSON;

  constructor(public data: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.data.getData();
  }
}
```

In the template `data` is rendered like:

```
<ul>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let value of data">
    <li>{{ value.title }}</li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

This works fine.

---

However, the problem is, that this list can contain up to 2000 entries. On this page is also a text input with attached events on keyup. In Chrome and Firefox this is Ok, but in Safari 11 the input slows down extremely. It only happens when the list is very long - short lists work like a charm.

---

My idea is now to detach the change detection for `this.data` in the component, as this list will never change once it is loaded.

I tried to use `ChangeDetectorRef` with `ref.detach()` which will (as expected) detach all changes.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I think the only way is to encapsulate this list into a separated component, then set change detector mode to `onPush()` and control it manually.

Comment: I've considered this as well. I thought I might get around creating a new component solely for this purpose. Thanks, @KarolTrybulec.

Comment: You could try running outside Angular https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#runoutsideangular

Comment: @FranklinPious I've thought about that too. But how do I tell Angular that the list is loaded at some point, so that it can be rendered at least once?

Comment: @lampshade You could use cdr.detectChanges();